# Python call to system program not working

Tags: python, linux, gcc

I wrote a little python script, intending to automate non-default options for gcc (on Kubuntu 14.04); the python runs without error now, and inserting a debug print statement (or changing the system command to 'echo') verifies the correct information is being passed, but I get an error from gcc saying

```
$ python gccm prog16
gcc: fatal error: no input files 
compilation terminated.
```

Here's the script I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv #get incoming argument
import subprocess #function to call an OS program

script, target = argv

# massage received argument into form needed for math.h linkage
target = "-o " + target + " " + target + ".c -lm"
subprocess.call (['gcc', target], shell=False)`
```

There are other additions I'd make to the gcc call (compile version options, stricter code checking, etc.), if I can get this to work correctly.  Based on the error message, it appears to be invoking gcc correctly, but the target source file isn't being found; could this not be running in the directory from which I invoke it?  If so, how can I get it to run from the correct directory (where I'm keeping my C source code files); if not, what else could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `shell=False`, your arguments to the sub-processes shouldn't be concatenated together. Instead, they should each be their own element in the `args` list:

```
subprocess.call(['gcc', '-o', target, target+'.c', '-lm'], shell=False)
```

On a related note, any reason why you're writing something like this yourself?  If you're looking to use a Python-based build system, have a look at [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

Comment: Well, that would have been a useful thing to mention in the documentation for subprocess (at least the version I found and read).  :p  I'm writing this myself because a) I can use the practice with python (it's only half a dozen lines), and b) I'm not really looking for a python-based build system, or any build system, to add another layer of things I have to learn while I'm trying to learn python itself, *and* relearn C, as well as c) I had no idea there was such a tool and didn't know to or how to look for it.

Comment: No problem - just thought I would point out a related application. Enjoy your project!

Answer (score 1):

If you have `shell=False`, then you must pass each argument separately into the `subprocess.call`.

Try this instead:

```
subprocess.call (['gcc', '-o', target, target + '.c', '-lm'], shell=False)
```